# Using Bull queue how to retry failed jobs with higher priority?

Tags: node.js, queue, bull-queue

Looking for a way to have [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/) retry failed jobs with a higher priority. More specifically, I would like failed jobs to be picked up before any non-failed job.

It's fairly easy to set stuff like 'number of retries', but nothing else regarding the retry policy afaik.

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this one as well.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731727/9642772) stack overflow answer suggests catching the error and adding it back to the queue with a higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the priority like this :

```
let newJob = await myQueue.add('queue-name', job.data, { ...{ priority: 1 }, ...job.opts });
```